# Ruby netx command after while loop

Tags: ruby, loops

I try to launch one command using while loop and the continue my script, but the loop never finish.Condition is `true` i don't want to put `false` because the command has to be executed every 10 minutes.

```
while true
  pid = spawn('xterm -e command')
sleep 600
Process.kill('TERM', pid)
 end
```

The same bash code work fine because i can execute the next commands of the script using `&` after `done`

```
while : ; do
        xterm -e command ; sleep 600 ; done &
        echo $! >/tmp/mycommand.pid
```

In ruby does the end statement block the script in my loop ? or the `true` value is not appropriate here ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You wrote an infinite loop, then you complain "the loop never finishes" (Yes, of course, it doesn't finish, it is an *infinite* loop), and then you say you want the command to be executed every 10 minutes, which means that you don't want the loop to finish?

Comment: Yes i miss some crucial point in my question sorry.I just want to be able to do the same code in ruby like in my bash code.Call a command every 10 minutes but without problem following the others commands in the script.Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want to create a thread:

```
Thread.new do
  while true
    sleep(1)
    puts 'inside'
  end
end

puts 'outside'
sleep(3)
```

And output:

```
outside
inside
inside
```